# Bottom tab menu in React Native not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my react native application I am trying to develop a bottom tab menu for android. When I press an icon of the menu to navigate to the page that it represents. I tried creating the menu and using the options property to create a button to use react navigation but without any luck. For more details I am using stack navigator in my App component for navigation. What can I do ?
Here is the code for the component where I am trying to show the menu:

```
const Discover = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
return (
<SafeAreaView className="flex-1 bg-white relative">
<Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Favorites"
          component={FavoritesScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: () => (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("FavoritesScreen")}
                style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  alignItems: "center",
                }}
              >
                <Text>Favorites</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

And here is the code for my App:

```
export default function App() {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Discover" component={Discover} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ItemScreen" component={ItemScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="FavoritesScreen" component={FavoritesScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

I am also leaving a picture of how my menu looks right now. For any advice I am grateful[image: Picture]